# MVVM pattern (Prism) and Xamarin Maps

Tags: google-maps, xamarin, mvvm, prism

Is there a way to be able to employ Xamarin Maps in MVVM pattern by frameworks like Prism? For e.g. to be able to capture pinning on the map in the view model without having to breaking MvvM architecture? Or type in an address to reflect on the map?

Answer (score 1):

Following this article about [bindable maps](https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/19840/binding-pins-on-map-view-to-collection) may help until Xamarin folks implement it as a built-in feature.